# Passing paintComponent to another class error

Tags: java, swing, class, graphics, jpanel

I am trying to have each of the objects paint themselves into the `JPanel` by passing `graphics` through but i am getting a `java.lang.NullPointerException` error.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Main extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    Main panel;
    Player mainPlayer;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Asteroids");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Main panel = new Main();
        frame.add(panel);
    frame.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        frame.setSize(500, 400);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        mainPlayer.paintComponent(g);
    }
}
```

And then this code is in a different .java file

```
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Player {

    public Player() {

    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    }
}
```

Does anyone know why this code isn't working?

It is giving me:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Main.paintComponent(Main.java:23)
```

Comment: Lets start with the fact that `mainPlayer` is not initalised any where in your code example

Comment: I do not feel very smart right now...

Comment: Don't worry, it happens to the best of us.

Comment: Welcome to the world of programming, where smart people are made to feel dumb ;)

Comment: Haha, I think i'm going to like it here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not instantiating mainPlayer.  Since the default value is null for uninstantiated object reference variables, you are getting a NullPointerException on line 23 when you are trying to dereference the variable.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for completely forgetting that

Answer (score 2):

The mainPlayer variable is what is causing you problems. You should add in your main method, panel.mainPlayer = new Player();
Because mainPlayer is by default null, you will have to set it to some instance of an object in order to use it and call its methods.

Comment: I added mainPlayer = new Player() and made it static.